# Trying to parse a shortcode using thunderer/shortcode

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, parsing, shortcode

I'm trying to add shortcodes to a WYSIWYG. I'm using [this library](https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode). I'm trying to parse this into an [accordion from bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse):

```
[panel]
[header]
Heading goes here
[/header]
[content] Content goes here [/content]

[header]
Heading goes here
[/header]
[content] Content goes here [/content]
[/panel]
```

My code looks like:

```
use Thunder\Shortcode\HandlerContainer\HandlerContainer;
use Thunder\Shortcode\Parser\RegularParser;
use Thunder\Shortcode\Processor\Processor;
use Thunder\Shortcode\Shortcode\ShortcodeInterface;

function processAgendaContent($content)
{

    $handlers = new HandlerContainer();
    $handlers->add('panel', function(ShortcodeInterface $s) {
        return "<div class=\"panel panel-default\">";
    });

    $handlers->add('header', function(ShortcodeInterface $s) {
        return '
    <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a href="#collapse1" target="_blank" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse1" class="btn-collapse">
    ' . $s->getContent() . '</a>
    </h4>';

    });

    $processor = new Processor(new RegularParser(), $handlers);

    echo $processor->process($content);
```

My issue right now is that when I'm trying to parse, it parses the opening tag but not the closing tag, and I imagine for that reason getContent() does not work. Any idea what am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the author of the Shortcode library. To fix your issue please change your `panel` shortcode handler body to:

```
return '<div class="panel panel-default">'.$s->getContent().'</div>';
```

Every shortcode handler controls what is returned from the whole shortcode text. You just returned a simple string and didn't include its content anywhere, that's why the whole text encapsulated by `[panel]` got discarded.

I hope that helps to better understand how this library works, if you have more questions I'll happily answer them here.